# HTML RichText WIdget within Datorama Issue

Tags: html, richtextbox, rich-text-editor

I am fairly new to HTML coding, so could really use the communities help here. I have a HTML RichText widget, which I am using to create a navigation bar within our data visualization tool, Datorama. Unfortunately, when you click on the menu items, it keeps opening the page within the widget and not loading the full page.

Here is the Code:

```
<nav class="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="About">
                    About
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Us">
                    Us
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Our">
                    Our
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="History">
                    History
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Latest">
                    Latest
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="News">
                    News
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="New">
                    New
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Arrivals">
                    Arrivals
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="On">
                    On
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Sale">
                    Sale
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link">
            <span class="menu__title">
                <span class="menu__first-word" data-hover="Contact">
                    Contact
                </span>
                <span class="menu__second-word" data-hover="Us">
                    Us
                </span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Could anyone please assist in adjusting this to when a menu item is clicked, it opens a new page?

Thank you,
-Nakul B.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Johnny from Datorama's Tier 2 Support,

Because the Rich Text works with iFrames, it means that the browser opens a new embedded HTML document within the active one, and links are opened within the embedded iFrame instead of the tab itself, or a new tab.

This can be controlled by working with the a tag's 'target' attribute, and the following options can be assigned:

**_blank** - new window or tab

**_self** - Opens within the same window or iFrame (default behaviour)

**_parent** - Opens the link within the parent frame

**_top** - Opens within the full body of the window

In the case mentioned, we should use the '_blank' attribute, and the following code should be used:

```html
<nav class="navigation">
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="https://google.com" class="menu__link" target="_blank">About Us
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link" target="_blank">Our History
            
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link" target="_blank">Latest News
            
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link" target="_blank">New Arrivals
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link" target="_blank">On Sale
            
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__link" target="_blank">Contact Us
            
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've also changed the structure of the a tags, and reduced the number of span within it, to increase readability. Now the links should open a new page/tab on click.

Please don't hesitate to contact us at support@datorama.com for further assistance for setting your widget up!

Comment: Hey Johnny, thanks for this solution! I will give this a go, and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!